# Uploading MySQL database to server?

Tags: mysql

I have created a website that has a MySQL database. I'm using phpmyadmin and xampp. Now I have a website to upload the files to (using Filezilla). How do I upload the MySQL database to the server and connect it to the website? I'm guessing there is already a tutorial somewhere but I couldn't find it.

Comment: phpmyAdmin has an import button where you import the file to.

Comment: You will have to export your MySQL database and then import it to your new server through phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

If you have your database file ready to upload then in phpmyadmin there is an import option as shown in the image below:

[image]

In order to connect it to your website will depend on your server side language choice...

Example with PHP to connect your website to your database (using `pdo`):

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=name_here;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root'; //change to your username
$password = '******'; //change to your password

try {
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

?>
```

Once you have that at top of your PHP file you can connect. This one way to do it via PHP.